# Quitar contra barras para formato json string

Tags: json, swift, string

Tengo un string dentro de un diccionario que estoy intentando pasar a jsonstring pero no me esta quitando las contrabarras y el servidor no se lo traga.

¿Alguna idea? El código es el siguiente:

```
let myBod = "\"Body\": {" +
        "\"type\": \"multipart\"," +
        "\"content\": [" +
        "{" +
        "\"contentType\": \"multipart/alternative; Boundary=\\\"0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\\\"\"," +
        "\"contentDisposition\": \"inline\"" +
         " }," +
         "{" +
         "\"contentType\": \"text/plain; charset=US-ASCII\"," +
        "\"data\": \"yappy\"," +
         "\"boundary\": \"--0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\"" +
         " }," +
        " {" +
        "\"contentType\": \"text/html; charset=US-ASCII\"," +
          "\"contentDisposition\": \"inline\"," +
         "\"data\": \"<html><body>yappy</body></html>\"," +
         "\"boundary\": \"--0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\"}]}"
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás intentando solventar el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITADA**

El problema está en el String.

Las barras son necesarias para distinguir el las comillas (") como un caracter parte de la cadena.

Para que puedas convertir esa cadena a JSON primero debe ser un JSON válido. Para ello puedes probarlo en ésta página [jsonViewerOnline](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Lo que he hecho para tu caso, es añadirle llaves de apertura y cierre al String para que así pueda reconocerlo como un JSON válido.

Te dejo el siguiente código que te convierte el String en JSON sin problemas

```
    var str = "\"Body\": {" +
               "\"type\": \"multipart\"," +
               "\"content\": [" +
                "{" +
             "\"contentType\": \"multipart/alternative; Boundary=\\\"0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\\\"\"," +
            "\"contentDisposition\": \"inline\"" +
             " }," +
              "{" +
        "\"contentType\": \"text/plain; charset=US-ASCII\"," +
        "\"data\": \"yappy\"," +
        "\"boundary\": \"--0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\"" +
        " }," +
        " {" +
        "\"contentType\": \"text/html; charset=US-ASCII\"," +
        "\"contentDisposition\": \"inline\"," +
        "\"data\": \"<html><body>yappy</body></html>\"," +
        "\"boundary\": \"--0__=4EBB0A76DFCD51048f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0A76DFCD5104\"}]}"

       print(str + "\n")
       var newString = "{" + str + "}"
       print(newString + "\n")
       let data = newString.data(using: .utf8)
       let object = try!JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
       print(object)
```

Puedes realizar pruebas sobre el PlayGround de XCode.

Comment: Te recomiendo [edit] tu respuesta argumentando tu respuesta. Por favor revisa: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.